# Netflix Conductor: How to get a set of workflows based on a timerange

Tags: workflow, netflix

I want to filter out the number of workflows I get back based on a time range. I explored the APIs from Netflix Conductor documentation page, however, I wasn't able to pick it apart and find the solution. The page mentioned a 'query' parameter, which is similar to a SQL like clause, but I can't find good examples online of its usage. Does anyone have any info on this that can help me. I want to essentially filter the data so I can get data starting from a specific date until when I executed the GET request.

https://netflix.github.io/conductor/apispec/#search-for-workflows

This is the page I used as a reference to get info on the 'query' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Query basically is the Elasticseach Query. Here is a [link to the official documentation regarding Query formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

Here are a couple of examples of Queries that I found working for me:

- `http://localhost:8080/api/workflow/search?query=workflowId="20c3f74f-71bb-4b59-8a61-f261b94123ef"`
- `http://localhost:8080/api/workflow/search?query=status="RUNNING" AND workflowType="kitchensink"`

As for filtering by the time range, you could use [range format of the query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges). Probably, what you need will look like two examples below:

```
date:[2012-01-01 TO 2012-12-31] //All days in 2012:
date:{* TO 2012-01-01}          //Dates before 2012
```